# Animating Height when scrolling a ScrollView

Tags: react-native, animation

So im trying to animate a view by changing the view's height when a user scrolls a specific scrollview. It looks fine on IOS although it has some jitter going on but the flickering is very visible on android. Here is my code.

**Scrollview's on scroll**

```
 onScroll={(e) => {         
     this.state.profileTabAnimatedValue.setValue(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
 }}
```

**height interpolate object**

```
const headerHeight = this.state.profileTabAnimatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0,1],
      outputRange: [1,100]
});
```

I will then apply the headerHeight  to a view to adjust it's height

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Animated event method:

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
  [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.profileTabAnimatedValue}}}]
)}
```

Also, if you don't want some weird behaviours like negative height or so, add this in your interpolation:

```
const headerHeight = this.state.profileTabAnimatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0,1],
      outputRange: [1,100]
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
});
```

Last thing is you can play a bit with throttling your events firing on your ScrollView with `scrollEventThrottle`, just read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrolleventthrottle)